# Convert VARCHAR to NUMBER with decimal on Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I'm having some trouble to convert `VARCHAR2` informations, like:

- -111.21
- 11.11
- -51.146610399175472

to `NUMBER`. I want to store these numbers on a `NUMBER(19,16)` column. Mostly of these values are coordinates (latitude and longitude).

I already tried different commands with different values:

```
select cast('-111.21' as NUMBER) from dual
select cast('-111.21' as decimal) from dual
select cast('111.21' as decimal) from dual
select to_number('-1.1') from dual
select to_decimal('-1.1') from dual
```

But I always receive the error:

> The specified number was invalid

This SQL:

```
select to_number('-134.33','099.99') from dual;
```

Works, but any change on the number (like change to `'-34.33'`) return the same error.

What I'm doing wrong here? Obviously I'm missing something here but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I need to pass a mask as parameter to the `to_number` function. Like `'999.999999999999999'`

So:

```
select to_number('90.79493','999.999999999999999') from dual;
select to_number('90.146610399175472','999.999900000000000') from dual;
select to_number('90.34234324','999.999999999999999') from dual;
```

works for different size of numbers.

Comment: Check your `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` value. If you change it to `.` as decimal separator then it should work also without number format.